# Why PgUp(^[[5~) or PgDn(^[[6~) input are considered 4 characters instead of 5 when taken from getchar?

Tags: c, input, io, getchar

I have this piece of C code

```
#include"stdio.h"

main()
{
    int x;
 char c;
    for(x=1;(c=getchar())!=EOF;printf("%d ",x++));
}
```

It prints x from to 1 to n, where n is nth character taken from standard input by getchar().

For any normal input like - single char 'a', it reads 2 chars 'a' and '\n'. So the count is 2. I understood that.

But, when I press PgUp or PgDn from keyboard the terminal have "^[[5~" or "^[[6~" stream of characters, so the output count should be 6.

5 from "^[[5~" and 1 by the '\n' terminater.

But the count is only 5, So what is actually happening?
How ^[[5~ is 4 characters?

I thought '~' might be considered as sentinel characters or something but if I provide "1~" the count is 3.

Friendly note - I am in danger of being blocked from asking anymore. I searched for the answer but couldn't find it. If you think this qustion must be removed, please tell me in comments.

Comment: change your print to `printf("%d %d\n", x++, c);` and you will see what is happening

Comment: Thank you @M.M for pointing that out. Edited now.

Comment: Thank you so much for that advice @M.M now i know whats happenening.

Answer (score 1):

The caret character (`^`) is traditionally used to print ASCII control characters, which don't have a standard visual representation. `^[` is a single character, `ESC` (0x1b).

As a note, you could print out the numeric values for each of the characters you read to see if there are any surprises (in this case, you'd find the low value that doesn't match the display).

Comment: Okay I understood that ^[ is a single character.  But if I give ^[ as input my code says it has 2 characters.

Comment: @Naresh That's because you're *typing* it. Press the Esc key instead, or Ctrl-`[`.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much @chrylis